# invalid character in identifier while ploting a regression model

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
print (X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print (X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = lm.predict(X_test)

## The line / model
plt.scatter(y_test, predictions)
plt.xlabel(“True Values”)
plt.ylabel(“Predictions”)

    File "<ipython-input-385-d55e9eec2917>", line 3
    plt.xlabel(“True Values”)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

i am trying to run this program but getting this error. can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: How are you editing this?  That looks like smart quotes, not real quotes.

Comment: Change `plt.xlabel(“True Values”)` to `plt.xlabel("True Values")`. It looks like you've copied the code from somewhere (here? https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6)

Comment: try the code with 'True Values' instead of "True Values". its because of keyboard settings.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. if someone else is also facing same issue then wanna say that try the code with '' instead of "". its because of keyboard settings.